# Tabix queries spanning chromosomes

Tags: tabix

I can do something like this:

```
$ tabix ${url} ${range}
```

where `${range}` spans a region on a single chromosome, *e.g.*, `chrA:X-Y`.

Can a `tabix` query span multiple chromosomes, *e.g.*, where `${range}` looks like `chrA:X-chrN:Y` (or similar), which returns data between `chrA:X` and `chrN:Y` (using either a lexicographical or natural sort order between `chrA` and `chrN`)?

*Note: I do not want to pass in a BED file of intervals. If it can't be done without passing in a separate file, that's fine. I only want to provide a one-liner to give to someone who can run `tabix` on their end, to do this type of query directly and remotely.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [htslib source code](https://github.com/samtools/htslib/blob/5c7ff9c6812f1e6ef1fd83ba73b8e42cfbabba93/hts.c#L2627-L2645), it seems like the answer is no, a single region specifier cannot span multliple chromosomes.

Seems like the closest you can get is to enumerate all the chromosomes as separate regions on the [command line](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html). So to get everything between `chrA:X` and `chrN:Y`, you would have to write:

```
tabix inputfile.gz chrA:X chrB chrC ... chrN:1-Y
```

(If you omit the end coordinate like `chrA:X`, the region encompasses `chrA` from the specified coordinate to the end. If only specify the chromosome name without the coordinates, like `chrB`, the region encompasses the whole named chromosome, and for the last chromosome, you can specify up to the desired point by starting from the beginning: `chrN:1-Y`.)

Comment: Okay, thanks, that worked great. I was able to order chromosomes as desired to write standard output in BEDOPS `sort-bed` order.